# flask-restful no such command

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm currently building a flask-restful app and i want to create a CLI command, i currently have this:
db.py: https://haste.themelvin.nl/osn4sl
api.py: https://haste.themelvin.nl/vNaAl4
but when i execute `flask init-db` in my terminal I get this error: `Error: No such command 'init-db'.`
does anybody know how i can fix this?

Comment: So I was trying to use a full flask tutorial with the flask-restful boilerplate and that didn't work. I currently have this simply piece of code and it should work. but it doesn't, i still get the error `no such command 'create-user' found`
any idea why?
code: https://haste.themelvin.nl/Lt9go7

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the instructions are listed in below:

1. Edit the configuration in the your `flaskr.py` file or export an
   `FLASKR_SETTINGS` environment variable pointing to a configuration
   file.
2. Install the app from the change directory to root of the project
   directory

   ```sh
   pip install --editable .
   ```
3. Be sure flask to use the correct application

   ```sh
   export FLASK_APP=flaskr
   ```
4. Initialize the database with command like this:

   ```
   flask initdb
   ```
5. And finally

   ```
   flask run
   ```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with 1 and 3?

Comment: Sorry for wrote the python file name wrong. I edited the post.